# JHipster/OpenAPI - Cannot define a schema type that contains an array of objects

Tags: jhipster, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using JHipster and OpenAPI to generate a Spring Boot project. After generating the project with JHipster, I copy my OpenAPI file into `src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml` and run the OpenAPI sub-generator with `mvnw generate-sources`. It fails with a ton of exceptions (see below).

Version info:

- JHipster 6.4.1
- OpenAPI 3 (3.0.1)

**Note**: There are a number of other SO questions related to this ([How to define an array of another schema in OpenAPI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827240/how-to-define-an-array-of-another-schema-in-openapi-3) and [Return an array of object in Swaggerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167981/return-an-array-of-object-in-swaggerhub)), and my file is structured in the same way. It all makes sense to me ... but it doesn't work.

So, here is what I have (schema definitions at the bottom of the file):

```
# API-first development with OpenAPI
# This file will be used at compile time to generate Spring-MVC endpoint stubs using openapi-generator
openapi: '3.0.1'

info:
  title: 'testEchoMicroservice'
  version: 0.0.1

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:9100
    description: Development server
  - url: https://localhost:9100
    description: Development server with TLS Profile

paths:
  /random:
    get:
      deprecated: true
      summary: Returns a random message
      description: Returns a random message
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Random response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
  /echo:
    post:
      summary: Echoes a specified message
      description: Echoes a specified message
      requestBody:
        description: Echo request
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Echo response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
  /history:
    get:
      summary: Get echo history
      description: Get echo history
      responses:
        '200':
          description:
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/EchoList'

components:
  securitySchemes:
    jwt:
      type: http
      description: JWT Authentication
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
  schemas:
    Echo:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
    EchoList:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'

security:
  - jwt: []
```

So, `EchoList` is just an array of `Echo` objects.

When I attempt to run the jhipster openapi sub-generator, it throws the following (Note: quite a bit of the stack trace has not been inluded because it exceeds SO limits. Upon quick inspection, it's repetition of the exceptions seen below):

```
> mvnw generate-sources
...
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ echo-service ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\JO24447\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.4\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\JO24447\\workspace\\OpenAPI\\entity-test\\target\\jacoco\\test\\test.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ echo-service ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.1.3:generate (default) @ echo-service ---
[WARNING] Exception while reading:
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 73, column 18:
          items: $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
                     ^

 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 73, column: 18]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException.from (MarkedYAMLException.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken (YAMLParser.java:359)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName (JsonParser.java:825)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose (ObjectMapper.java:4056)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree (ObjectMapper.java:2551)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readWithInfo (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:154)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:58)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation (OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext (CodegenConfigurator.java:410)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:458)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:705)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 73, column 18:
          items: $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
                     ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue (ScannerImpl.java:870)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens (ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken (ScannerImpl.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce (ParserImpl.java:558)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent (ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent (ParserImpl.java:168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken (YAMLParser.java:355)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName (JsonParser.java:825)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:255)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize (JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose (ObjectMapper.java:4056)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree (ObjectMapper.java:2551)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readWithInfo (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:154)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation (OpenAPIV3Parser.java:58)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation (OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext (CodegenConfigurator.java:410)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:458)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:705)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[WARNING] Error snake-parsing yaml content
io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$SnakeException: Exception safe-checking yaml content  (maxDepth 2000)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.getSingleData (DeserializationUtils.java:300)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader (Yaml.java:524)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load (Yaml.java:437)
    at io.swagger.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree (DeserializationUtils.java:137)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.deserializeYaml (Swagger20Parser.java:83)
    at io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser.readWithInfo (Swagger20Parser.java:64)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.readWithInfo (SwaggerParser.java:32)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation (SwaggerConverter.java:96)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation (OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext (CodegenConfigurator.java:410)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:458)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:705)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.520 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-14T11:15:25-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.1.3:generate (default) on project echo-service: Code generation failed. See above for the full exception. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange that I missed this. Apparently I must have had the file structured as follows:

```
components:
...
  schemas:
    Echo:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
    EchoList:
      type: array
      items: $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
```

Because, after putting the reference on its own line (and indented) everything now works.

```
components:
...
  schemas:
    Echo:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
    EchoList:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
```

What a sneaky, subtle (and easy to make) gotcha.